How to Send a Request with LIST & Parameters to a restAPI Post with Json in WinForm C#
I am stuck at the end to find code for sending a request with LIST & parameters to a POST REST API with Json in Winforms and C#.
I have a local web server with a Web API that has a POST method that has parameters, the address is : https://localhost:44328/api/hitung
With Postman, I can send a request with parameters like this
POST > Body > RAW > JSON

and have some response returned from with these 4 parameters:
{
    "retailercode": "CJF00055",
    "orderitems": [
        {
            "rownumber": 1,
            "productcode": "100535",
            "qty": 5
        }
    ]
}

And Postman will return a response like this:
{
    "retailercode": "CJF00055",
    "orderitems": [
        {
            "rownumber": 1,
            "productcode": "100535",
            "qty": 5,
            "orderprice": 8727,
            "percentdisc": "D1.5",
            "disreg": 1.5,
            "valuediscreg": 654,
            "totaldisc": 654
        }
    ]
}

What I have tried to code, but still get an error from my MessageBox

An error has occurred.

The problem is I don't know how to create parameter list for the request in my C# code.
'''
{
"retailercode": "CJF00055",
"orderitems": [
{
"rownumber": 1,
"productcode": "100535",
"qty": 5
}
]
}
'''
Please can someone try to help me to solve my problem?
This is my model list class:
public class Root0
{
    public string retailercode { get; set; }              
    public List<orderitem0> orderitems { get; set; }
}

public class orderitem0
{
    public int rownumber { get; set; }
    public string productcode { get; set; } 
    public decimal qty { get; set; }

    public decimal orderprice { get; set; }
    public string percentdisc { get; set; }      
    public decimal disreg { get; set; }          
    public decimal valuediscreg { get; set; }
    public decimal totaldisc { get; set; }  
}

My Winforms code has some errors and fails to collect the response:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public async void coba5()
{
     try
     {
         string url = "https://localhost:44328/api/hitung";
         System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

         var requestData = new Root0 @"{""RetailerCode"" : ""CJF00055"", 
                         ""orderitems"": [
                         { 
                         ""rownumber"": 1,
                         ""productcode"": ""100535"",
                         ""qty"": 5
                         }]}";

         string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestData);
         var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
         var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
         string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         MessageBox.Show(responseContent);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    coba5();
}


First things first, change ex.Message to ex.ToString() to get your entire exception message. That might lead you to debug deeper into the problem once you have a detailed error message.. Also I am not sure why you want to encode using Encoding.UTF32 which is less common, usually UTF-8 is commonly used. Maybe that could cause the error in your case

i have change to (Encoding.UTF8)   &  ex.ToString(), still have error, cause the source error is the (Parameter List) format in my code

What is the complete error you are getting right now when you hit the API. Also it would be helpful if you could show your API endpoint code.

if i hit API in my Code VS C#, then the massage Box will show ("Message": "An error has occurred.")  if i use Postman with this Parameter {
"retailercode": "CJF00055",
"orderitems": [
{
"rownumber": 1,
"productcode": "100535",
"qty": 5
}
]
}   will show Result Response

So even when you have put ex.ToString(), you only get An error has occurred ? I would also suggest that you put try-catch block in your API method and then see if you can get a detailed error.

i also show my WebAPi project code there, is different project, web Base Api, regards

yes the source problem is in my WinForm project, idont know to declare code Request parameters with LIST Api, like "rownumber",  "productcode", "qty", because is under List orderitems.

Remove this line string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestData); and just send requestData : var content = new StringContent(requestData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

thanks Rahul, your answer is Right, i try it & it Works, thanks

In your case, you are serializing your Root model twice on this line:
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestData);

Now since you are already generating your Root model as a JSON on this line:
     var requestData = new Root0 @"{""RetailerCode"" : ""CJF00055"", 
                     ""orderitems"": [
                     { 
                     ""rownumber"": 1,
                     ""productcode"": ""100535"",
                     ""qty"": 5
                     }]}";

You should not Serialize your Model and rather send the requestData directly to StringContent:
var content = new StringContent(requestData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

